# User experience site review/opinions

Tags: usability-testing

Asking user experience experts to have a look at the following site www.socialbite.co.za.

The client is asking for rounded buttons and hamburger style toggle navigation. I need some expert advice if this is best practise and what other tools I can use to make sure the user downloads the app from the playstore or sign-up

Comment: This is not how this website works. Please provide embedded screenshots / of the website, and please make your question general enough to help future readers. We are not a free review service.

Comment: I just visite the site and the very first thing I notice is, I don't even know what this website is for. Here's what you get / your benefits "  as description?  I think you should give some description.

Answer (score 1):

As per the UX guidelines, the hyperlinks are used for navigation (nouns) from one page to another or to a different site, but buttons are meant for actions (mostly verbs)

NN/g has published very good articles about the hamburger menu / navigation, here are the links which may help you to understand in detail:

**Hamburger Menus and Hidden Navigation Hurt UX Metrics**
https://www.nngroup.com/articles/hamburger-menus/

Comment: many thanks guys. Anyone willing to give some feedback on the site in terms of great user experience, or give it a rating as it is currently?

Comment: www.socialbite.co.za